# Removing Battery and running the laptop in plugged-in mode?

Tags: battery, charger

Is it fine, if I remove the battery from my system and run in by having it plugged-in by the charger? Will it cause any damage to the system?

My Laptop is an HP Probook 4320s (which comes under the category of 'Corporate Laptops'), it has 2nd Generation Intel i3 Processor, 3GB RAM, 280GB, almost zero graphics card.

Comment: No, unless a blackout... :)

Comment: It depends on the laptop. Some are specifically designed to run this way and do so without issue. Some won't be able to run at full speed. Some won't run at all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have edited my question to say about the particular model I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counter argument to those who inform you (correctly) that some laptops might be damaged by running without a battery is that the battery life is greatly extended when you take it out after it is done charging. Apparently the heat and overcharging greatly reduce a li-ion battery's service life. Of four identical Dell Inspirons in my faculty, the one that has its battery removed after charging (charging with the laptop unpowered) far outlasted the three that where left in, and even a second battery replacement on one of them!

Comment: Modern batteries *cannot* be overcharged when used with their intended chargers. That's decades old information.

Answer (score 2):

Some motherboards uses the batteries to stabilize input DC voltage.

Without the battery pack a mobile [PSU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_%28computer%29) can generate "[ripples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_%28electrical%29)"(alternate voltage added to a continuous voltage level) on DC voltage that could affect the operation of some devices and probabilly causing some damege on it if working this way for a long time. Here is a ripple example:

[image]

Comment: Some laptops will even put themselves into a 'preserve power' mode when no battery is present, even if it is plugged in directly to a power outlet. My dell does this so I have to keep the dead battery in place to be able to reach 'performance' modes.

Comment: @SaultDon: That's a *bad* idea. The laptop *needs* the battery's charge to handle load bursts as the CPU comes out of internal low power modes. You are making it think the power is stabilized by the battery when it's not. The lower-than-expected voltages can result in higher-than-expected internal currents, which can cause serious damage. The surge of increasing current will also build a large magnetic field around the cable that connects the brick to the laptop. When that magnetic field collapses as the voltage stabilizes, it induces an EMF that can cause damage to the laptop.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Wow... Didn't know that, thanks! Maybe I shouldn't be so cheap and fork some bucks for a new batt.

Comment: Let me just point out that while what I said is 100% accurate and it *could* cause damage, there are no reported cases of actual damage to my knowledge. But the laptop definitely does slow down because the designers believed the battery was needed to stabilize the power under those conditions.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Fair enough. Appreciate the extra info. I should add that my particular laptop has been without a chargeable battery for almost 4 years now and I haven't seen any damage or hardware failure... yet.

Answer (score 1):

I routinely run my Toshiba laptop without its battery.  It seems fine.  I've used it this way for years and it is still working well.  As geekosaur said though, I have encountered laptops that won't run without a battery in place.  I've always assumed these are the ones that require the battery to stabilise the input voltage.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the laptop; you're unlikely to break it, but some laptops will refuse to power on without a battery in place (that is, they always draw power from the battery).